# Can I get a SQL Injection by checking how many rows my database has?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I made a short code which shows me exactly how many users are registered in my website.

```
$user_query = "SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id";
$user_counter = ($user_query);
$user_counter_run = mysqli_query($conn, $user_counter);
$user_counting = mysqli_num_rows($user_counter_run);
```

I dont have much experience about SQL Injections... Im just wondering, can i get a SQL Injection by this code?

Comment: No, the above isn't open for SQL injections since it's a hard coded query without any dynamic values (like user input). I would recommend that you read through some articles about what SQL injections are, and it will become much clearer.

Comment: Thanks Magnus! I will check about SQL Injections to learn more about it

Comment: **That's NOT how you check the number of rows in the first place.** it should be a SELECT count(*) query. Imagine there will be a million rows. Gonna select them all only to get the count?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the parenthesis in `$user_counter = ($user_query);` trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the query is pre-defined. If the user was entering even a part of the query, then SQL injection would be possible.